# convert LPTSTR to string

Tags: c++, string, lptstr

I am getting text from a Window and it returns in LPTSTR. I have to turn it into string or else I have to rewrite a lot of my code. Also What is a LPTSTR and how is it different from a string?

Comment: LPTSTR can be either `char*` or `wchar_t*` depending on whether or not you are using Microsoft's idea of Unicode

Comment: Part of the reason to just use wide strings in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

LPTSTR is a string, it's just not constant.

You can use it like a regular char * if as long as you don't define UNICODE in your application. The difference between a unicode and normal string is the length of the character. In unicode it is either 2 or 4 and in standard programs it is 1 byte.

As some people might point out, you're not the only one to ask this question. This is usually a topic of confusion for people learning to program in the Windows environment. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for some clarification, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/). I'd also recommend viewing their [desktop API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a lot of useful information that may help you with future inquiries.